# Windows Easy Transfer in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10-upgrade, windows-easy-transfer

I want to upgrade to Windows 10 but heard there is no more Windows Easy Transfer.  Is it still possible to backup on windows 7 and still open the file in Windows 10?
Or is there something else I should try?

Comment: There's a tool provided by Microsoft called USMT (User State Migration Tool) and is available in ADK (Assessment and Deployment Kit). The problem is, it's a command-line executable and you have to have enough experience with the usage. If you know what to do, you can move mountains. If you don't, it's likely you end up a mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Windows Easy Transfer is really gone.

Options you still have:

1. Do a manual transfer: copy files you want to an external drive, and move them over to the new Windows 10. Pros: it's free. Cons: no programs transfer, takes time, will probably forget some of them. I'd use this if most of the stuff is not that important and you don't have any programs you can't redownload.
2. Use a 3rd party tool. There are several out there, starting with backup tools like Acronis, but the proper tool would be a migration tools such as Zinstall. They have an [Windows 10 Easy Transfer alternative](http://www.zinstall.com/how-to/how-to-use-windows-easy-transfer-on-windows-10), which will copy files, settings etc., and they also have a tool that can actually [transfer programs to a new PC](http://zinstall.com/how-to/how-to-transfer-programs-and-files-to-new-computer), i.e. full migration.
   Pros: it transfers everything, even programs if you use the advanced version. Fast, won't lose stuff. Cons: it costs money...

Comment: zinstall ist pretty costly with more than $100. I would recommend Laplink PCMover Professional which is recommended by Microsoft which is around $50 and also copies all applications: http://laplink.azurewebsites.net/feature_overview/

Answer (score 1):

If you still have a PC with Windows 7 on it, then you can copy the tool from that PC.

You'll have to copy the folders `%windir%\system32\migration` and `%windir%\system32\migwiz` (usually `C:\Windows\system32\migration` and `migwiz`.

You can then start the tool from `migwiz\migwiz.exe`

Answer (score 0):

Use Laplink PCMover Professional which is recommended by Microsoft which is around $50 and also copies all applications: http://laplink.azurewebsites.net/feature_overview/

Comment: You are repeating your comment